# How did Chewbacca get C-3PO's parts back after being captured?

Tags: star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back, c-3po, chewbacca

We know how Chewbacca [managed to find C-3PO's parts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/66031/how-did-chewbacca-find-c-3pos-parts) after he was blown into pieces.

But how did he get them back after being captured by Vader and why would the Stormtroopers allow Chewbacca to have a toolkit and a droid in his cell?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to *[Thank the Maker](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Thank_the_Maker)* from *[Star Wars Tales](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Tales_6)* Issue #6, Darth Vader had it delivered to Chewbacca's cell.

[image: Thank the Maker]

[image: Thank the Maker]

While not made explicit, it's implied that Vader wanted C-3PO to be fixed.

The comic's canon status is ambiguous, but according to Wookieepedia, it has "elements of continuity."

Comment: Alas, poor 3PO... I knew him well, Lando